# Will MySQL redirect a read request to the master after a certain time?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I can't find what variable controls this or any information about the time limit.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Go ahead and delete it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you mean by "certain time"? Replication Lag? Query Response Time?

In a simple Master/Slave(s) infrastructure, the distribution of the reads/writes operations should be done with a load balancer or directly in your apps.

Max.